Pre-Sheaf on locally compact abelian group
Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group. We can define a pre-sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on G by $$\mathcal{F}(U) := \widehat{\langle U\rangle}$$ for any open set $U$, where $\widehat{\langle U\rangle}$ denotes the Pontryagin dual of $\langle U\rangle$ and if $V$ is any other open set with $V \subset U$, then $res_{V, U}(\psi \in \mathcal{F}(U)) = \psi|_{\langle V\rangle}$.
It clearly satisfies the properties of being a pre-sheaf and satisfies the locality axiom, but seems to fail to satisfy the gluing axiom, basically because we are dealing with continuous homomorphisms defined on open subgroups of $G$, instead of just continuous functions defined on open sets.
What does the sheafication $\mathcal{F}^+$ of $\mathcal{F}$ look like? From what I understand, in general, the sheafication of a pre-sheaf is supposed to "localize" the properties satisfied by the sections of the pre-sheaf. So in this case, given an open set $U$, would $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ consist of continuous functions $\langle U\rangle \to \mathbb{S}^1$ that locally act like homomorphisms?

Use \langle,\rangle
